# Campaigne privileges

Tags: campaign, insufficient-privileges

I have a link on my campaigne's record for mass mailing. However, this doesnt work due to insufficient privileges. Although I'm a marketing user on my user's record, and I can import leads (on the profile)

Any troubleshoot?

Comment: have you checked for `campaign member` permissions ?

Answer (score 0):

Enable the **Mass Email System Permission** for the resp. user's profile:

[image: Mass Email]

Comment: I have this privilege checked too. I troubleshoot the probleme which is whitin the custom link I define.
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Can you then share the link you are using?

Comment: @TrinityLoveLace - if custom link goes to a VF page, and your profile doesnt have access to that VF page, this error could occur